# consul installation in aws ubuntu machine

Tags: consul

Any one have the link to install and configure the consul in aws ubuntu machine it would be more help full to me

Need to explore the consul tool...

1. i am following official document its not helping out.

   2. Even i followed the Digital Ocean doc no use for me.

Getting the error

> **2016/04/06 12:14:41 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leade**>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the Consul server configuration?? Are you running a cluster or standalone?

Comment: (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-consul-in-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-consul-in-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14-04) i am following this doc while i am running consul members in client it through error **Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8400: getsockopt: connection refused**